# C++Builder TFileStream compatibility between debug and release app versions

Tags: c++builder, tfilestream

Using TFileStream to write various values and Strings to a file I found that I can't share file between the debug and release versions of my application.
Looking further it seems that enum types are not write/read the same length using TFileStream.
Example :
If I write to the stream something like using the debug version :
fsStream->Write((void*)&FInstrumentStatus, sizeof(TInstrumentStatus));
it can't be read from the release version, and opposite is the same.
Other values like Strings, int, double, float seems fine.

Since I do have many files created from the debug version, what can I do to get the release version read/write the same?
Thank you,
rwil

Comment: That has nothing to do with debug vs release.  Your compiler settings are simply setup differently between the two builds.  There are compiler settings and `#pragma` directives for controlling the sizes of enums (ie, short/compact enums vs integer-sized enums). But, this is really the fault of your code for not writing the data in a portable format to begin with, now you are dealing with the consequence.

Comment: Thank you Remi for the answer. English is not native for me, I was not thinking debug vs release.
It is a personnal project started long time ago with the first release of C++Builder 1 by Borland around 1995 and it was the way that I use over the time to save things in a file.
So yes, I know that if I ever decide to go further,  a portable format like you mentioned will be necessary. 
If you have a library or ssomething that you can point out I would be glad to know.
RWil

Comment: Thank you again Remi.
It was the "Integer-sized enums" to be set on false.
Now it's fine between versions.
Cheers,
RWil